# jQuery's GET is acting up for me. Using CodeIgniter. It returns source code for a view instead of one value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to test the jQuery `GET` method, but what I am getting as result is completely insane. All I am trying to do is call a function from my controller with jQuery and then display the echoed value in a div within my view. Below is my code and finally a breakdown of the problem I am encountering.

**Controller**

```
public function generate_suggestions2() {

        echo "James";   
}
```

**View** `views\suggestions_v.php`

```
<body>
//This DIV is used a button to call the jQuery function
<div id="next_btn">
   <p>Click here to display a name</p>         
</div> 

//In this div the value retrieved by the jQuery should be displayed
<div id="listB"></div>

//This is the function that calls the function within my controller
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( "#next_btn" ).click(function() {

        $.get("core/generate_suggestions2/",
        function(data) {

            $( "#listB" ).html(data);
        });
    });
</script> //For some reason I need to put the script at the end of the body. When it's in the head nothing happens when I click the button. Also something I do not understand.

</body>
```

Now the problem is that when I click the DIV `next_btn` it does NOT display the `James` in the DIV `listB`.

Instead it populates the DIV `listB` with my source code from my main view `views\core_v.php`
I have no idea how this is even remotely possible, so please if you have a clue or even better you know what I am doing wrong please tell me. I am trying to get this to work for the past three days without any success or progress :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code in your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "$( "#next_btn" ).click(function() {

        $.get("<?php echo site_url().'/core/generate_suggestions2';?>",
        function(data) {

            $( "#listB" ).html(data);
        });
    });"
</script>
```

Also delete the `</script>` tag just right before this block comment.

Regarding this comment you have:

```
//For some reason I need to put the script at the end of the body. When it's in the head nothing happens when I click the button. Also something I do not understand.
```

It is because the DOM is not yet fully loaded and Javascript executes its code when the browser has finished loading the DOM you are referring to. So you either have to put it after the DOM element you want to edit, like you do now or you could use `$(document).ready(function(){
}
);` .
Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: This is what I needed this entire time `<?php echo site_url().` Thank you so much!! Also the `</script>` was only here somehow pasted it by accident. Thanks mate.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot do this. Post your code and you might get help from me or other users.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I had to figure out how to pass html divs and anchors and other styling with the code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This line is pretty strange:

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">
```

Try to delete first closing tag 'script' on it.